# modulo operation using numbers in exponential form

Tags: c, modulo

I have a small question. How come when I write this:

```
ComPrimSideCtr = (ComPrimSideCtr + 1) % 1.0E+6;
```

I get the error message: #31 expression must have integral type, but when I write:

```
ComPrimSideCtr = (ComPrimSideCtr + 1) % 1000000;
```

I don't get any error messages at all? Isn't 1.0E+6 the same number as 1000000?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `1000000` and `1000000.` are not the same.

Answer (score 4):

The e-notation (scientific notation) in C like this `1.0E+6` is used only for floating-point constants.

Since C doesn't allow floating point operands for `%` operator, it emits that error message.

---

> Isn't 1.0E+6 the same number as 1000000

No, `1.0E+6` is equivalent to `1000000.0` which is by default assumed as a `double` constant (double precision floating point). While `1000000` is a integer (`int`) constant.

Comment: Hm, ok, so there is no way of writing that number in an easier way? It's kind of hard to see what number you have when it is that large.

Comment: To avoid repeating it many times, just save it in a `const` integer and use that varaible again and again.

Comment: @user3514815: `#define TEN_TO_POWER_6 (1000000)` should help.

Comment: @user3514815 : I hope my answer solved your problem. If it didn't please comment, if it did then please accept it. Accepting it will save other users' time as accepted answer will not attract other users unnecessarily, as you have been already provided with correct solution. Thanks.